# Load a page with a Form using AJAX, And submitting the form from the Main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two pages in my folder, ***main page*** & ***secondary page*** and it contains the following.

### main page:

**HTML**

---

```
<div id='show'></div>
```

**AJAX**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.post('sec_page.php',{form: form}, function(form){
      $('#show').html(form);
   })
})
```

---

### secondary page:

**HTML**

---

```
<form action='sec_page.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
<div id='vview'></div>
```

**AJAX**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').submit(function(submit){
      submit.preventDefault();
      var Submission = $(this).serialize();
      var Action = $(this).attr('action');
      $.post('sec_page.php',{Submission : Submission}, function(vview){
            $('#vview').html(vview);
      })
   })
})
```

**PHP**

---

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo "The form has been Submitted!";
}
```

---

The **main page** shows me everything inside the **secondary page**, Which is a **form**, If i clicked on the **submit** button from the **main page**, It redirects me into the **secondary page**, And i don't want that to happen, Since i want the form to be submitted from the **main page** and shows the `echo` in it too;

So i tried to put the **AJAX** inside the **secondary page** and didn't solve the problem, Moved it to the **main page** instead, And didn't still the same problem;

So in brief, How can i submit the **form** from the **main page** without refreshing it or redirecting to the **secondary page**.

If not possible, I would like to know a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` does not include submit buttons.
Only when you submit the form normally the button you used to submit the form will be sent.
For ajax you can manually put that value in the data or have a hidden input.

```
<form action='sec_page.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='submit_name' value="submit_value">
    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_name'])){
   echo "The form has been Submitted!";
}
```

also you pass the serialized data alone as the data parameter

```
  var Submission = $(this).serialize();
  var Action = $(this).attr('action');
  $.post('sec_page.php', Submission, function(vview){
        $('#vview').html(vview);
  })
```

Also you have to attach the submit event handler to the form not the submit button

```
$('form').submit(function(submit){
```

Comment: Doesn't `.serialize()` recognize  `name` same as  `value`?

Comment: I mean, I just want to tell `AJAX` that the button is clicked only, Either by `name` or `value`, So as i understood from you, I have to add another hidden button, To define the `POST` request, did i get it right?

Comment: You can do that to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Well, AJAX still redirects from the main to secondary page, But the PHP works.

Comment: It works, But when i click on the `submit` button from the `main page` it keeps redirecting me to the `secondary page`, Even after changing everything as you said.